# How do i undo what the windows 10 Program Compatibility Troubleshooter does?

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting, compatibility, safe-mode

I am trying to undo what the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter did.

Essentially it makes the program boot in Windows compatibility mode: XP.

With it running in Windows compatibility mode: XP. I need to reactivate the program as the program thinks its a different/new computer(makes sense).

Theses settings where applied with the "try the recommended settings" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the the property of program,

Go to compatibility tab and remove tick from 'Run this program in compatibility mode for:' and too remove tick from all the below options

**Right Click Program > Properties > Compatibility** (remove tick from all the options)

Thanx